# How to solve this simple nonlinear ODE using the Galerkin's Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, galerkin-methods

I'm trying to solve a more complicated differential equation using the Galerkin's Method, but before that, I'm trying to understand how I would solve this simpler one:

$$ \cfrac{d^2u}{dx^2} + u^2 = 1;\quad\text{where} \;u(-1) = u(1) = 0.$$

I have to use the basis functions $\;\phi_j(x) = \sin(j\pi x)\;$.

Therefore, an approximation to the solution has the form:

$$ u(x) \approx \sum_{j=1}^{N} c_j \phi_j(x)$$

I notice that this choice of basis functions automatically satisfies the boundary conditions.

If I plug this approximation into the equation, I get:

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{N} c_j \phi_j''(x) + \left(\sum_{j=1}^{N} c_j \phi_j(x)\right)^{\!2} = 1.$$

So the residual can be defined as:

$$ r(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{N} c_j \phi_j''(x) + \left(\sum_{j=1}^{N} c_j \phi_j(x)\right)^{\!2} - 1$$

and the Galerkin's Method imposes that ${\displaystyle \int_{-1}^{1}} r(x) \cdot \phi_i(x)\,dx \:=\:0,\;$ for $i = 1,2,\dots,N$.

When I substitute the residual in the integral above, however, I face the nonlinear term

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \left(\sum_{j=1}^{N} c_j \phi_j(x)\right)^{\!2} \cdot \phi_i(x)\,dx,$$

which evaluates to zero for any $i$ and $j$.

So this means that the nonlinear term $u^2$ at the original equation doesn't make any difference at all?

I'm pretty sure to be missing something here...

Comment: First integral: \begin{align*}u''+u^2&=1\\ u''u'+u^2u'&=u'\\ \frac{u'^2}{2}+\frac{u^3}{3}&=u. \end{align*} This you can reduce to quadratures, since it's separable. Not sure about the boundary values, though.

Comment: $$ \left(\sum_{j=1}^{N} c_j \phi_j(x)\right)^{\!2}$$ is an even function and $\phi_i(x)$ is odd so the integral is null. In cases in which the nonlinearity is odd the residual in not necessarily null.

Comment: @Cesareo interesting. In that case, is it impossible to use the Galerkin Method?

Comment: Use instead $\phi_k(x) = \cos((2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}x)$. You were approximating an even function through a sum of odd functions.

Comment: Reduce to quadratures just means you can write the solution as an integral, in this case, $$\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{2u+c_1-2u^3/3}}=\pm x+c_2. $$ The integral on the LHS is difficult - looks like an elliptic function. But it might give you information on the solutions would could be helpful - I fully realize you are in numerical land, here.

Comment: Is it possible to solve the system of nonlinear equations in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be observed, the numerical solution to

$$
u''-u^2=1, \ \ u(-1) = u(1) = 0
$$

looks like an even function

[image]

and $\sum_{k=1}^N c_k \phi_k(x)$ with $\phi_k = \sin(k\pi x)$ is a sum of odd functions. As a result, the residue conditions establishes $c_k = 0$ as the best solution. Using instead $\phi_k(x) = \cos\left(\frac{(2k-1)}{2}\pi x\right)$ we will overcome this problem obtaining for $N = 3$

$$
u(x) = 3.30587 \cos \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)+0.126786 \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi  x}{2}\right)-0.00597599 \cos \left(\frac{5 \pi 
   x}{2}\right)
$$

with an absolute error as shown below

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to solve the system of nonlinear equations in the same way?

Comment: From the nonlinear equations for $c_k$ in $\int_{-1}^1 r(x, c_1,c_2,\cdots, c_n)\phi_k(x)dx = 0,\ \ \{k=1,\cdots,n\}$ you get a system of $n$ nonlinear algebraic equations in $c_k$ to solve.  Here $r(x,c_k)$  is the residue from the ODE.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%3Dx%2By%2Cy%27%3Dx-y+solve+for+x%2Cy

Comment: For a system of two equations, we get two residuals, do I understand correctly?

Comment: Choosing the right base functions, OK.